# How to read from a SQL with multiple fields from Native SQL

Tags: java, spring-boot

First of all, apologize for my grammatical errors. My English level is not good.

I'm trying to read multiple fields that will be columns in a table. But I don't know how do it. Because, I've tried using a loop from getResultList() from query.

I'm using spring boot (jpa + hibernate) with postgsql.

The idea is instead of next code:

```
public List<Object> readTable(String nameTable) {
    String SQL_COLUMN_TABLE_ID = "SELECT table_id FROM " + nameTable + " ORDER BY table_id asc;";
    String SQL_COLUMN_GEOM = "SELECT GeometryType(geom) FROM " + nameTable + " ORDER BY table_id asc;";
    String SQL_COLUMN_PROPERTIES = "SELECT CAST(properties AS text) FROM " + nameTable + " ORDER BY table_id asc;";

    List<String> table_id = executeSQLReadTable(SQL_COLUMN_TABLE_ID);
    List<String> geom_type = executeSQLReadTable(SQL_COLUMN_GEOM);
    List<String> properties = executeSQLReadTable(SQL_COLUMN_PROPERTIES);

    List<Object> results = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i=0; i<table_id.size(); i++) {
        List<Object> item = new ArrayList<>();
        item.add(table_id.get(i));
        item.add(geom_type.get(i));
        item.add(properties.get(i));

        results.add(item);
    }
    return results;
}
```

To use this:

```
public List<String> readPerfectTable(String nameTable) {
        String SQL = "SELECT table_id, CAST(properties AS text), GeometryType(geom) FROM " + nameTable + " ORDER BY table_id asc;";
        return executeSQLReadTable(SQL);
    }
```

In this part, I do not know how to use the results of multiple fields from select:

```
private List<String> executeSQLReadTable(String SQL) {
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Query query = em.createNativeQuery(SQL);
            List<?> list = query.getResultList();
            for (Object item : list) {
                // Here WTF!
                results.add(item.toString());
            }
        } catch(Throwable e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
        return results;
```

}

Comment: Each element of the list returned by getResultList() is an array of objects. And each array contains 3 elements: the table ID, the properties, and the geom. You could use your debugger, or a simple System.out.println(), to find out by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I solved :D 
Thanks a lot :D

```
private List<Object> executeSQLReadTable(String SQL) {
    List<Object> results = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery(SQL);
        List<?> result = query.getResultList();
        Iterator<?> itr = result.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
           Object[] obj = (Object[]) itr.next();
           List<Object> row = new ArrayList<>();
           row.add(Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(obj[0])));
           row.add(String.valueOf(obj[1]));
           row.add(String.valueOf(obj[2]));
           results.add(row);
        }

    } catch(Throwable e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
    return results;
}
```